# Open Windows Forms Application from VBS

Tags: winforms

I have created a windows forms application

Is there a way i can make a VBS script open the application and pass a parameter to it?

Thank You

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx

Comment: and what would I need to add to the applications form1 which loads to pick up the parameter?

Comment: Parse the Main() arguments.

Comment: sorry to ask youve been very helpful but do you have an example of how to parse the main() arguments? thank you

Comment: Without having any idea what you want to pass?  No.  Leave this project on the shelf until you learn more.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Thanks!

```
Sub WhatEver()
    Dim strArg() as string
    strArg = Command().Split(" ")
    ' strArg(0) is first argument and so on
    '
    '
End Sub
```